# How to get Win11 to request "Plain 2" paper type when printing to Canon printer?

Tags: printer, paper

My Canon MF744C laser printer supports different paper types according to paper weight (Plain 1, Plain 2, Plain 3, ...). The common 80g/sqm paper that I am using is supposed to be configured as "Plain 2".

The problem is that Win 11 seems to be requesting "Plain 1" paper when I select "Plain" paper in the printing preferences. Consequently, the paper refuses to print initially, and says "Load A4/Plain1".

Any suggestions on how I can avoid that?

The only idea I had was to pretend in the printer settings that the paper is actually more lightweight and set it up as Plain1. I assume that might reduce the printing quality.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the preferences? During print from the application, or in windows itself?

Comment: I am trying to set-up the printer in general, so that I do not have to change it all the time. For instance: Printer & Scanners > MFC742/744C > Printing preferences > Paper/Quality > Media = Auto select | Plain | Heavyweight paper

Comment: There are 2 different preferences in the printer settings, and you're changing the wrong ones. Look for Printing Defaults, and change those. Its in the Advanced tab I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The printer itself needs to know what type of paper is loaded. You can set this from either the front panel display, or from the printer's web interface.

For instructions on how to access the setting from the front panel, see pg 162-164 (pg 170-172 in the PDF) of the [User's Guide](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/is-sensys-mf744cdw.html?type=manuals&manualid=tcm:13-1829880). Info on setting it via the web i/f ("Remote UI" in Canon speak) starts on pg 436 (pg 444 in the PDF)

Answer (score 1):

The control panel applet has 2 different places where you can set settings.
So far you've been changing the Printing Preferences.

What you want to do is setting the Printing Defaults.

Go to Control Panel, Devices and Printers and right-click your printer, then Printer Properties.

Instead of clicking the preferences... button, click <kbd>Change Properties</kbd> in order to reopen the dialog as administrator.

Now head over to the Advanced tab and press Printing Defaults.
[image]

Setting the Printing Defaults will make these settings the default for when you are in a program. If you there click printing properties, and the properties panel opens, the settings you've entered in Printing Defaults will show up. (Not going to the settings window will still print with these settings of course)

This allows you to set settings but they're not fixed, and can be changed manually for a single print.

This also allows you to add your printer twice, and configure each instance with different defaults, so you can just print to a specific printer if you want to, for example, print to a different tray, or have one set for black and white, and the other for color, etc.